# Abstract class Custom Deserialization for RestController

Tags: java, spring, json-deserialization

I have a abstract class `PluginTemplate`, inherited by 3 child classes

`PluginTemplateA, PluginTemplateB, PluginTemplateC`.

I have a some other class which has a map having PluginTemplate list.

```
    @JsonDeserialize(using = PluginDeserializer.class)
    public class PluginContainer {
        // map stores enum to template list mapping, enum can be used to identify template type
        Map<PluginTemplateEnum, List<PluginTemplate>> pluginTemplatesList;
        other variables....
    }
```

I send object of PluginContainer on post request to other service which uses RestController

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/plugin/generateDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String generateDetails(@PathVariable Long interfaceId, @RequestBody List<PluginContainer> containers) throws Exception {
        // other code
    }
```

I know for sending json, I will need a custom json deserializer for the abstract class PluginTemplate.

I have started writing a json deserializer which is like this

```
public class PluginDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<PluginContainer> {
    @Override
    public PluginContainer deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // what should I write here
    }
}
```

How should I identify type of PluginContainer using the Map key value, and deserialize it accordingly in this method.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the TreeNode keys or directly get the Value (TreeNode) by using `TreeNode.get`

```
 public PluginContainer deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        TreeNode treeNode = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        Iterator<String> nameItr = treeNode.fieldNames();
        while(nameItr.hasNext()) {  //Iteratae Over keys
            String key = nameItr.next();
        }
        //or you can just get the required value for key
        //i.e.
        treeNode.get("fieldName");

    }
```